# Calling a popUp Component inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a normal react Modal Component, what I want to do is something like this

```
const someWorkHandler = () => {
mycustomFn.ConfirmModal({
title: "bla bla",
okFunc : ()=>{},
...
})
}
```

and my component is like

```
const ConfirmModal = ({title, okFunction , ...}) => {
return //JSX
}
```

Comment: What would you want to achieve at the end of the day? Your question is not elaborative.

Comment: i have a table and i want to access the row Id that has been clicked without setting a state using function argument